# Construct an object with a string literal

Tags: c++, string, constructor, initialization, string-literals

I have the following class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CLS
{
   int value;
   string str_value;

public:

    CLS(int param) { value = param; }

    CLS(string param)
    {
       str_value = param;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CLS a(2);
    CLS b = 3;
    CLS c("4");
    CLS d = "5";  // Error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'
}
```

I searched for the reason why it is error with no luck.

Is it correct to construct with a string literal? 
if no, why?
if yes, what is wrong with my code?

I am using gcc 5.3 with Code::Blocks 16.1.

Comment: I note that this builds just fine under VS2017. It is worth remembering that a string literal is not the same as a `std::string`.

Comment: Is that a full example? Any headers included? What is `string` in your case?

Comment: @Artur R. Czechowski - It is a full example (I added the headers). `string` should be `std::string` I guess.

Comment: Try adding a constructor for `const char*`. As @Artur R. Czechowski said, a `std::string` is not the same as a string literal.

Comment: @Rook MSVC has an extension to allow multiple implicit user-defined conversions. Cranking up the warning level should produce a diagnostic.

Comment: @Quentin interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first, `"4"` is not `std::string`, it's `const char[2]`. Then

`CLS c("4");` is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), the constructors of `CLS` will be examined for initializing `c`. `CLS::CLS(string)` is picked up here, because `const char[]` can be implicitly converted to `std::string` via user-defined conversion (i.e. by `std::string::string(const char*)`).

`CLS d = "5";` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> - If `T` is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is not `T` or derived from `T`, or if `T` is non-class type, but the type of `other` is a class type, **user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of `other` to `T`** (or to a type derived from `T` if `T` is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

That means user-defined conversion sequences is required to convert `const char[2]` to `CLS`. Even `const char[]` could be converted to `std::string`, and `std::string` could be converted to `CLS`, but only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one [implicit conversion sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). That's why it's rejected.

(emphasis mine)

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>     2) **zero or one user-defined conversion;**
>     3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.

BTW: If you change it to using `std::string` as the initializer expression explicitly it'll work fine. e.g.

```
CLS d = std::string{"5"};  // pass a temporary std::string constructed from "5" to the constructor of CLS

using namespace std::string_literals;
CLS d = "5"s;              // "5"s is a string literal of type std::string (supported from C++14)
```

Comment: So the one user-defined conversion requirement also applies to implicit conversions? Because otherwise `const char[2]` -> implicit `const char*` -> user-defined `std::string`, right?

Comment: @Rakete1111 (1) Yes, only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one implicit conversion sequence; (2) I can't get your intent, `const char[2]` -> `const char*` is not user-defined conversion but standard conversion which could be more than once.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my point: If only 1 user defined conversion is allowed, then `const char[2]` -> `const char*` doesn't count, and `std::string`'s constructor can be used (which is 1 user defined conversion). But why is it not allowed then?

Comment: @Rakete1111 That's because we need to convert `const char[2]` to `CLS` for copy initialization.

Comment: Oh, so no intermediate conversion is allowed?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, otherwise user-defined conversions would be able to be chained.

Answer (score 8):

```
CLS a(2); 
CLS b = 3;
CLS c("4");
CLS d = "5";
```

`a`and `c` are initialised with [direct initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). `b` and `d` on the other hand use [copy initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

The difference is that for copy initialisation the compiler searches for a (single) user defined conversion from (in case of `d`) `char const *` (this is a bit inaccurate, see end of answer) to `CLS`, whereas for direct initialisation all constructors are tried, where `CLS(std::string)` can be used​ because there's a conversion `std::string(char const *)` available.

**Detail:**

`"5"` is a (C) string literal. It's type is `char const [2]`. So first, a user defined conversion from that type to `CLS` is searched. Because none is found, the standard conversion from `Type[N]` to `Type *` (with `Type` = `char const` and `N` = `2`) is applied, resulting in a `char const *`. Then the compiler tries to find a user defined conversion from that to `CLS`. Because it doesn't find one, and there are no more standard conversions it could try available, compilation fails.

Comment: You mean "[...] user defined conversion from (in case of `d`) `char const[]` [...]"? `"5"` can decay to `const char*`, but it is a `const char[2]`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 there you go, I initially left decay out of the answer to keep it focussed on the conversions.